# jQuery adding a div after a generated table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am sure i have the right logic here and tried after and insertafter but does not seem to work... any ideas?

JS:

```
if(content) {
    var $table = $('<table/>');
    $table.addClass('product-table');
    $table.append(
        '<tr><td><img src="' + content[0].image + '" class="thumbnail"/></td>' + 
        '<td><strong>' + content[0].title + '</strong></td>' + 
        '<td>SKU: ' + content[0].sku + '</td>' + 
        '<td>&pound;' + content[0].price + '</td></tr>'
    );
    $table.after('<div class="button-container">' + 
                     '<a href="#">view cart</a>' + 
                     '<a href="#">checkout</a>' + 
                 '</div>');
    $(notice_content).find(notice_inner).html($table);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`after` method requires that the target element (`$table`) be in DOM - which it isn't until next statement with `.html` method.

Just move line with `after` call after the line with `html` call:

```
$(notice_content).find(notice_inner).html($table);
$table.after('<div class="button-container"><a href="#">view cart</a><a href="#">checkout</a></div>');
```

Useful references:

http://api.jquery.com/after

Comment: Ahh yea would make sense... thanks for the helping hand. I assumed if was moved after the html($table) would not be included but i just tried and worked a treat! thank you very much!